# How to keep In App Purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

So i implemented my In App Purchase correctly but i have an issue. Once I unlock a feature in my app such as a banner or a label I do not know ho to make it stay on screen after I shut the app down.

When I reopen the app I have to click the purchase button again and go through the whole process to restore it back.

How do I make the purchased items stay live instead of going through this process again?

Comment: Did you search for "iOS IAP restore purchases"?

Comment: Apple's documentation appears in the search results: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html

Comment: @NicolasMiari Yes I have. Will having that figured out automatically bring back my mouth purchases or will I have to say call a function to bring them back?

Comment: I think you call a function. But in your case, you can keep the "unlocked" state in the user defaults database on disk (NSUserDefaults). Restoring is more for users who move to a new device.

Comment: @NicolasMiari What exactly would I save in NSUserDefaults? This is my first time ever doing this. Thanks!

Comment: A boolean indicating whether the user has unlocked your paid content. If it is there, it means they previously purchased it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to go about this.  The easiest solution is to use [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setBool:forKey:).  Something like this should get you started in the right direction:

```
// this goes in the success callback of the IAP code.
if(purchaseWasSuccessful) {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"IAP_ITEM_1_PURCHASED"];
}
```

Then, when you start your app, or in the `viewWillAppear` method of the specific view controller that displays your purchased content, you can simply do something like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if([userDefaults boolForKey:@"IAP_ITEM_1_PURCHASED"]){
    // You know the item was purchased, so display your purchase here.
}

// Or, the inverse is just as easy:
if([userDefaults boolForKey:@"IAP_ITEM_1_PURCHASED"] == NO){
    // You know the item has NOT been purchased,
    // so display your banner to prompt them here.
}
```

Comment: Wow this actually works well but I have an issue. Say I am have a soundboard and I am making the user purchase more sounds if they like. until they purchase when they tap the button you get an alert saying "would you like to but...". If they do then they get the sounds. How would you then disable the purchase alert from coming back up when they tap that same button after the purchase? Sorry for the long comment!

Comment: Just add a check in before the code fires that shows the alert: `if([userDefaults boolForKey:@"IAP_ITEM_1_PURCHASED"] == NO) [purchaseAlert show];`

Comment: Ok great. I did this but then the buttons doesn't get functionality until I start the app again since I have the NSUdefaults key in the viewDidLoad. How wold I achieve this without starting the app over?

Comment: Really, you should ask a new question for this, since it's completely unrelated to the original question that you asked.  You need to implement a way to notify the controller of the purchase, which is exactly what `NSNotificationCenter` is for: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/

Comment: Thanks for the help I appreciate it! and will do.